# VirtualBox / VMware virtual machine SHALL NOT have access to local network?

Tags: windows-7, windows, virtualbox, vmware

Hi i am using windows 7 VM on both hypervisor virtual box / vmware .what i want is that the VM has access to internet but cannot access the local network how can i achieve this in any 1 of them hypervisor.

Host OS: Windows 10
VM OS: Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this could help resolve your question.
[How to give virtual machine access to the Internet, but block from LAN?](https://superuser.com/questions/117204/how-to-give-virtual-machine-access-to-the-internet-but-block-from-lan)

Thanks,
Eleven